# missing: GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS GTK3_LIBRARIES

Tags: gtk3, 23.10

I'm getting this error:

```
raphy@raohy:~/wxWidgets$ cmake -B builddir
-- Setting build type to 'Debug' as none was specified.
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "1.8.1") 
-- Looking for GDK_WINDOWING_WAYLAND
-- Looking for GDK_WINDOWING_WAYLAND - not found
-- Looking for GDK_WINDOWING_X11
-- Looking for GDK_WINDOWING_X11 - not found
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find GTK3 (missing: GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS GTK3_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  build/cmake/modules/FindGTK3.cmake:51 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  build/cmake/toolkit.cmake:81 (find_package)
  build/cmake/main.cmake:15 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:100 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

But `libgtk-3-dev` is already installed:

```
raphy@raohy:~/wxWidgets$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk-3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.10ubuntu1).
libgtk-3-dev is already the newest version (3.24.38-5ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.


raphy@raohy:/usr/include$ ls -lah | grep gtk
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1,4K mar 16  2023 canberra-gtk.h
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4,0K dic 22 19:17 gtk-2.0
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root 4,0K dic 23 12:28 gtk-3.0
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root 4,0K dic 22 10:11 gtk-4.0
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4,0K dic 31 11:47 gtkmm-4.0
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4,0K dic 22 19:17 gtk-unix-print-2.0
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root 4,0K dic 29 13:26 webkitgtk-4.0


raphy@raohy:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ls -lah | grep libgtk3
-rwSr--r--   1 root root   35K set  1  2022 libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
```

And in `.bahrc` :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/include/gtk-3.0
export GTK_PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

OS: Ubuntu 23.10

```
raphy@raohy:~$ pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
-lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz     
-latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 
-lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

`cmake` :

```
raphy@raohy:~$ which cmake
/usr/local/bin/cmake

raphy@raohy:~$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.28.1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

How to make Ubuntu detect gtk3 library ?

Comment: I wonder why your cmake is looking in `/usr/local/share/cmake-3.28/Modules`? Did you install cmake from somewhere other than the Ubuntu repository? BTW what is your end goal? Are you trying to build a version of libwxgtk3.x that is different from that in the repo?

Comment: Hi @steeldriver! I don't remember now how I installed `cmake`, but it seems installed fine: ``` raphy@raohy:~$ which cmake
/usr/local/bin/cmake
raphy@raohy:~$ 
raphy@raohy:~$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.28.1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
``` . I'm trying to configure, compile and install wxWidgets : https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/tree/master

Comment: OK but why not use [libwxgtk3.2-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/libwxgtk3.2-dev) from the Ubuntu universe repository?

Comment: Please [edit] with `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`

Comment: Hi @DanielT  I updated my post above with : `raphy@raohy:~$ pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
    -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz     
    -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 
    -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 `

Comment: That means that the libraries are found to be installed properly in the pkg-config layer. As steeldriver said, the problem is likely to be with your cmake. It is recommended to uninstall any locally installed versions. If that's difficult, you can just open your `~/wxWidgets` using the CLion IDE, which manages cmake well

Comment: @DanielT installing and using CLion IDE is the only way to manage and fix the probably mis-configured and mis-installed cmake?

Comment: @Raphael10 No, but it's the easiest. If you don't remember locally installing stuff, you can try `sudo mv /usr/local /usr/local.bak`, `rm -rf builddir`, then rerun `cmake`.

Comment: Thank you both steeldriver and @DanielT . I solved removing the previous messy CMake installation and installing it again from scratch

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver

Comment: @Raphael10 Please post the solution as an answer not a question edit

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED Thanks @DanielT and @steeldriver:

it was an issue related to my previous, probably messy, CMake installation

I removed everything related to CMake installation, compiled and installed it again from scratch

And everything went fine afterwards